# How to set the padding or margin or any property as a percentage of elements dimension and not parent container dimension

Tags: html, css, padding

I want to style elements but when I use `padding: '50%'` I want to set it 50% of the element height and not the parent element width

Comment: You should look into this page - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: this won't work: (1) percentage is based on the height of the element (2) the height of the element will increase after adding the padding (3) we have a new height so we need to recalculate the padding again (get back to (1) and you have an infinite loop)

Answer (score 1):

Percentage-based padding is based off the [width of the parent container](https://css-tricks.com/oh-hey-padding-percentage-is-based-on-the-parent-elements-width/).  That's just the way the CSS specification works.  I'm not aware of any padding-related syntax that is based off of height.  However, you could dynamically calculate and set the desired padding with javascript.  Something like [Element.clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) might be a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

-make a variable and assign to it a value of your element height

-for padding use calc() function to calculate it based on that variable